# Visual Studio Code плагин для перехода с зажатым Ctrl + LeftMouseClick, к методу на который нажали

Tags: visual-studio-code, клавиатура

Что включить или что установить в Visual Studio Code, для быстрого перехода к методу на который нажал(с помощью клавиш `Ctrl + LeftMouseClick`)?

Comment: F12 не подойдет для этой задачи?

Comment: @Сергей Татевосян  У меня и он не работает .  и я ещё в Qt привык к Ctrl + LeftMouseClick )

Comment: У меня с Python работает ctrl + клик. Возможно у вас не установлено расширение для языка программирования, на котором вы пишете, или это расширение не поддерживает данную функциональность.

Comment: У вас слева под списком файлов отображается структура (outline). Если это окно пустое, значит редактор не в состоянии парсить структуру для текущего языка и соответственно не может выдавать подсказки по классам.

Comment: @insolor как расширение называется ? Для C#

Comment: @IvanTriumphov, ms-vscode.csharp

Comment: @insolor Спасибо ) у меня включено , но все равно это не работает для меня

Comment: @insolor странно спустя время заработало